# How do I merge data from one table on one server to another table (same table name) located on another SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I need to merge a table say table1 located on server1 to table1 (same table) located on server2.

Actually I am asked to do this via ssis package

Comment: Setting up a linked server would probably make life easier.

Comment: Thanks @DanBracuk for your answer. Actually I am new into all these can you please tell me something more In details ?

Comment: Your google search string is `sql server linked server`.

Comment: For SSIS, I searched for "SSIS union multiple sources" and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl7oOlXBgKU)

Comment: You should have two connection manager one for table 1 server and another linked server table 1.either you have to use execute sql task select * from table1 union all select * from [linkedserver].table2

Comment: @Thangadurai.B  sir I need the package to run daily. And I am confused a bit as whenever the package would run it shouldn't load the previous data which has already been loaded Can you guide me more ?

Comment: @user7540144 I think you need a scd type, Refer [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2010/09/29/slowly-changing-dimension-using-ssis/)

Comment: I will have to study how to use SCD @Thangadurai.B  thank you again!

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Thangadurai.B  sir is SCD TYPE 1 suitable in my case ?